# Unable to add app administrator

Tags: facebook-apps

I have one account which I am closing (http://www.facebook.com/UrbanDystopia - email address: urban@urbandystopia.com) and I have already opened another under my name (http://www.facebook.com/david.manning.336333 - email addresses: davem@roseandmoon.com and david.manning.336333@facebook.com).

I am closing http://www.facebook.com/UrbanDystopia and I am the administrator of two apps - Bbblackdog (266537753438090) and CanCon (385773268120508) - therefore I "must either delete or transfer ownership of them before deactivating".

I want to transfer the ownership of both of them to my new account, but when I attempt to add a new admistrator to either one of them, I get this: "davem@roseandmoon.com is not a Facebook user" and also "david.manning.336333@facebook.com is not a Facebook user" and also "david.manning.336333 is not a Facebook user".

It won't let me add my new account, which does exist and those are the e-mail addresses to the new account.

As there is nowhere one can e-mail Facebook anymore to ask for help, I came here as a last resort after reading **everything** on Facebook about apps I could, none of which answered this question.

Can anyone please assist?

Dave M.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is related to this issue

[Creating A New App For Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9034805/creating-a-new-app-for-page)

Just like your new account is not verified.

Comment: I built the apps for other sites I had built, so I contacted the owners of the sites, who were also on Facebook, and made them admins. They will make my new account an admin after I verify it. Thanks for the replies.